# Find $\nabla f$ at the point $(-1, 2)$ where $f(x, y)$ = $\sqrt{2x+3y}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

> Find $\nabla f$ at the point $(-1, 2)$ where $f(x, y)$ = $\sqrt{2x+3y}$.

How to solve this problem?

I know that gradient of a function is given by,
$$grad(f) = \nabla f = \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}i + \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}j$$

$$\implies \nabla f = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2x + 3y}}i + \dfrac{3}{2\sqrt{2x + 3y}}j$$

Now I think I've to put $(-1,2)$ here.

So,
$$\implies \nabla f\bigg|_{(-1,2)} = \dfrac{1}{2}i + \dfrac{3}{4}j$$

What to  do now? I'm not sure if I've interpreted the question properly or not.

Comment: You've interpreted it correctly. But result for $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ is wrong.

Comment: @OğuzhanKılıç is it correct now? I think it was a typing mistake. and do I have to do anything further with this question? Or just $i/2 + 3j/k$ the final answer?

Comment: @user983206 That is the final answer. The gradient is a vector-valued function, so for each point in $\mathbb{R}^2$ it assigns a vector in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: @AsierLópez-Gordón Okay and thanks a ton for help, you guys are awesome!!! :D